# Mission Timeline Problem, only Take Off Command executed

Tags: java, dji-sdk

I'm trying to move my drone through a set of 2D coordinates like my code below
However, after I pressed the start timeline button, the drone only took off and didn't move to any point
I don't know what happens with my code right now as I've tried to follow DJI Sample Code for the MissionControl part
Please have a check a help me with this
Thanks in advance
Here is my code

```
private void initTimeline()
{
    List<TimelineElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    mMissionControl = MissionControl.getInstance();
    final TimelineEvent preEvent = null;
    MissionControl.Listener listener = new MissionControl.Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable TimelineElement TimelineElement, TimelineEvent event, DJIError error)
        {
            updateTimelineStatus(TimelineElement, event, error);
        }
    };
    showToast("Initialize Time Line System");
    elements.add(new TakeOffAction());

    GoToAction set_altitude = new GoToAction(new LocationCoordinate2D(0,0),2);
    elements.add(set_altitude);

    GoToAction go_2 = new GoToAction(new LocationCoordinate2D(1,1),2f);
    elements.add(go_2);

    GoHomeAction go_home = new GoHomeAction();
    elements.add(go_home);

    mMissionControl.scheduleElements(elements);
    mMissionControl.addListener(listener);
}

private void startTimeline()
{
    showToast("Start Time Line");
    mMissionControl.getInstance().startTimeline();
}

private void stopTimeline()
{
    showToast("Stop Time Line");
    mMissionControl.getInstance().stopTimeline();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I answered you in email but I see a few issues in your code:

The GoToAction is telling the aircraft to move to location 0, 0 (latitude/longitude) at a elevation 2 meters.

There are a few issues with this move.

First, unless you are flying at location 0, 0 (or very near the location) then the aircraft will return an error similar to "TOO_FAR, indicating the move is beyond the flight distance limits.

The second issue is the altitude, I believe there is a minimum altitude allowable but I'm not certain.

Are you really flying in the middle of the Atlantic, at location 0, 0?  If you are not, I suggest trying a GoToAction with a location nearer to where you are taking off.  The sample shows a calculation to move 3m and I suggest you could use that and calculate a location 3m away from takeoff (using the aircraft's home location and moving from that).

Also, the mission listener will report errors (the last parameter DjiError) reports any issues with the timeline; when not null, I suggest logging the error and it will inform you what the problem is and make correction easy.

Best of luck!